# loop a javascript function like in php foreach

Tags: javascript

I want to execute this function below 3 times but each time with a different value:

```
  socket.broadcast.to(role).emit('login', {
   onlineusers: list
  });
```

I have 3 roles: non-mods, mods and admins. The value for `list` varies for each role like this:
`non-mods => nonmodslist, mods => modslist, admins => adminslist`

I tried:

```
 roles = {non-mods : nonmodslist, mods : modslist, admins : adminslist}
 
 for(let {non-mods, mods, admins} of roles) {
  socket.broadcast.to(role).emit('login', {
   onlineusers: list
  });
```

but I really dont know what to do from there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code

```
let roles = {'non-mods' : nonmodslist, 'mods' : modslist, 'admins' : adminslist}

for(let rolename in roles) {
  socket.broadcast.to(rolename).emit('login', {
  onlineusers: roles[rolename]
});
}
```

Comment: will `list` vary each time according to the role in turn?

Comment: updated the answer now yes list will vary for each role

Comment: I get an error that says: roles is not iterable

Comment: `let rolename in roles` updated in the answer as well

Comment: Im not getting the values. Are you sure about rolename in `to()`?

Comment: in `to()` the value will be `'non-mods', 'mods', 'admins' `  & in `onlineusers` the value will be `nonmodslist, modslist, adminslist`

Comment: yes, its supposed to be like that but its not working and since there is no error displayed I cant debug it.

Comment: Yes i am sure it is working

Comment: Maybe the socket cant do more than 1 emit at a time?

Comment: maybe, but this is the exact answer to what you wanted in question

Comment: Thanks, I will try debugging it.

Comment: accept the answer if it worked for you, it will help other users as well.

Comment: I did because its the right code. However, seems like for this case I have to try a different approach because for some reason to() is not parsing `rolename`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for of` loop with `Object.entries` and deconstruction

```
let roles = {'non-mods': nonmodslist, 'mods': modslist, 'admins': adminslist};

for (let [role, list] of Object.entries(roles)) {
    socket.broadcast.to(role).emit('login', {
        onlineusers: list
    });
}
```

Comment: not working but there is no error either.

Comment: The loop should be executing 3 times with different role and list values each time. You haven't shared the socket related code so I can't make a comment on that.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that the socket cant emit more than 1 time simultaneously.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be socket.to(... without broadcast

Comment: without broadcast it will send it back to the sender each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var x = 0; x < roles.length; x++){
   socket.broadcast.to(roles[x]).emit.....
}
```

try it like this;

you want to set up an index (x) to iterate through roles, stopping once it reaches roles.length.... then you can access the specific role with that index

Comment: will `list` vary each time according to the role in turn?

Comment: no, list is defined outside the loop so it will not change unless you change it inside the loop aswell

Comment: btw welcome to the forums, if i've answered adequately please upvote :)

Comment: thank you. However, `list` is supposed to vary each time accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Object iteration can be performed using Object.keys(objectReference);

```
roles = {non-mods : nonmodslist, mods : modslist, admins : adminslist}
for(roleKey of Object.keys(roles)) {
    console.log(roles[roleKey]);
    // Perform operation using roles[roleKey]
}
```